# Is there a way to change the font size of a flextable caption?

Tags: r, markdown, font-size, caption, flextable

Is there a way to change the font size of a flextable caption?

I have used the set_caption() command, which works fine, but I don't like the size of the font when I knit to HTML from Markdown.

Comment: use css as shown here https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/articles/display.html#captions