# How to change flextable caption layout?

Tags: r, text-alignment, caption, flextable

I am building a flextable and I need the caption to be left-aligned. However, when I add a caption, it is always centered. I am exporting the table to docx. I am aware there is a related post here: [Is there a way to change the font size of a flextable caption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552572/), but it refers to tables that are knitted to html in markdown.
I would appreciate your help.

This is my example code:

```
require(flextable)
tab <- data.frame("Variable" = c("Reference Norm", "Suject", "Cutoff"), "Indicators"= c("Content 1", "Content 2", "Content 3"), "Reference Norm" = c("", "Content 4", "Content 5"), "Subject" = c("", "", "Content 6"))
tab <- flextable(tab)
tab <- add_footer_lines(tab, values = "Note.")
tab <- set_caption(tab, "This caption should be left-aligned.")
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your code there so people can have a better idea of what you've tried so far?

Comment: You need to read the documentation here: https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/set_caption.html. You can use arg `style` to change the associated paragraph style of the caption